# what should I do if I want to refer a full name of a function in swift?

Tags: swift, enums

Since ***sqrt*** is the name I should refer, are there other ways I can refer a function(e.g.  the full name :sqrt(double))?

I know sqrt is the legal name to be referred, but it's just a shorter writing, can I write a full name of sqrt function?

```
import Foundation

class CalculatorBrain{
private var accumulator: Double = 0.0
func setOperand(operand: Double){
    accumulator = operand
}

var operations: Dictionary<String, Operation> = [
    "√" : Operation.UnaryOperation(sqrt), // (sqrt(double))
]

enum  Operation {
    case UnaryOperation((Double)->Double)
}

func performOperation(symbol: String){
    if let abc = operations[symbol]{
        switch abc {
        case .Constant(let aa):
            accumulator = aa
        case .UnaryOperation:break
        case .BinaryOperation: break
        case .Equals: break
        }
    }
}

var result:Double{
    get{
        return accumulator
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with enumerations, associated values, or any of that. `sqrt` just references a function without calling it.

Comment: yes, what should I do if I want to refer a full name?

Comment: What does that even mean?

Answer (score 1):

Because `sqrt` is the function's name. You are not calling it, nor do you wish to do so; you are *referring* to it. And the bare name is how you do that.

Comment: Might want to read my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_references_and_selectors

Comment: so what should I do if I want to add a full name?

Comment: @WuchangLi What do you mean "full name"? Someone already asked that, and you still haven't clarified.